# Unable to Run Midnight Commander (MC) on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shared-library, midnight-commander

Mc is installed on the server but i am unable to run it. The error i get:

```
mc: error while loading shared libraries: libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libssh2-1 is installed, no idea why is it giving the error. How can i fix the issue?

Comment: You may be able to solve this problem by doing `ldconfig` (there is no harm in doing that) or, if that doesn't work, finding `libssh2.so` on your system and creating a symbolic link in the same folder: `sudo ln -s libssh2.so libssh2.so.1`.

Comment: Already ren ldconfig but didin't help.When i run dpkg -L libssh2-1 its says : dpkg-query: package 'libssh2-1' is not installed. But running: apt -qq list libssh2-1 shows libssh2-1/trusty 1.4.3-2 amd64. Is the package installed ? I can't find it in lib directories either.

Comment: Also the problem is the server doesn't have access to internet can only move packages and install locally.

Comment: No, it is not installed. `apt-cache policy libssh2-1` will tell you that. You can download the `.deb` file from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libssh2-1), move to your machine and install with `dpkg`.

Comment: @Jos, Thanks, i installed libssh2-1 package along with mc-data, other dependency package of mc, and it started to work.

Comment: @kulfy I have just posted one.

Answer (score 1):

Errors with a message like this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libXXX.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

(for some value of `XXX`; in your case, replace `XXX` by `ssh2`) are not uncommon. They can often be solved by creating a symbolic link. First, find out in what directory the shared file is expected to be found. You can do that by running `find -name libXXX.so`. Most often there will be a file `libXXX.so` found in some subdirectory of `/usr/lib`, where this mechanism is widely used.

Let's say there is a file `/usr/lib/YYY/libXXX.so`. Now navigate to that directory:

`cd /usr/lib/YYY`

and create the link:

`sudo ln -s libXXX.so libXXX.so.1`

The link name `libXXX.so.1` is taken from the error message. It is the name of the file that was not found. Now whenever the system looks for `libXXX.so.1` it will use `libXXX.so`.